# How to plot 2 coef in matlab to show their relation to each other for specefiec interval

Tags: matlab, plot

I've 2 coefficient (Ki , Kp)

[image]

How can I plot Ki(y axes) and Kp(x axes) that shows their relation to each other in a 2 axes plot in matlab for interval  w =(0 , 0.4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to:

- define the `omega` data range
- implement the equation of the two coefficients `kp` and `ki`. You have to make usre to use the notation

  - `./`, `.*`, `.^` to perform these operations on the arrays element-wise
- use `plot` to plot the `ki=f(kp)` over the `omega` interval

A possible implementation could be:

```
% Define omega data
omega=0:.01:0.4;
% Evalaute kp over omega range
kp=(38.6068*omega.^2-0.37)./(0.1288*omega.^2+0.1369);
% Evalaute ki over omega range (also using kp coeff.)
ki=(18.58-0.3589*kp).*omega.^2/0.37;
% Plot the data:
%   x data: kp
%   y data: ki
plot(kp,ki,'r','linewidth',2)
grid on
% Define the x axis label
xlabel('Coeff. kp','fontweight','bold')
% Define the y axis label
ylabel('Coeff. ki','fontweight','bold')
% Define the title
title('ki=f(kp) - \omega=[0:0.4]','fontweight','bold')
figure
plot(omega,kp,'r','linewidth',2)
hold on
plot(omega,ki,'b','linewidth',2)
grid on
legend('kp','ki','location','best')
xlabel('\omega','fontweight','bold','fontsize',20)
```

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Best Regards . HelpFull